# Wordpress lost users

Tags: wordpress

[Picture showing WP-users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhUK7.png)I can't log in to my WordPress site using my admin account. Or with any other account either. I get the message "Invalid username". When I try to reset the password by entering username or e-mail adress I get the message "Invalid username or e-mail". I have access to the WP-database trough phpMysqladmin. In the wp-user table I can see all users and e-mail addresses. It seems to me WP somehow lost contact with the database. I tried with a new password in the database using the MD5 function. No luck.

Link to the site: http://www.saxessbyalex.se

I have added a new user in the wp_user table. I get the same message. "Invalid user". On my testsite hosted by the same hotel it worked just fine.

Does anybody know what to do to get access to the administrator dashboard?

Comment: Read the whole question! I explained that I can see users in the database. I have the "admin" account with administrator privileges. I tried to reset password using the username. Then I get the message "Invalid username". I tried using the e-mail and get the message "Invalid e-mail". Though I can see the account in the wp-database. I have set a new password for "admin" in wp_user with the function MD5. But that doesn't seem to matter at all since "admin" is not recognized by WP.

Comment: I am sorry but the message 'Invalid username' really does mean that WordPress has connected to the database and could not find the username in the database. Is it possible that you are looking at the wrong database? Please don't be angry if you think this is a stupid question - I am really trying to help you.

Comment: The wp-version was very old. It is updated and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: I have read the WordPress code and found that user login is processed by get_user_by() which is a pluggable function which means it can be replaced by a plugin. Is it possible that your installation is using a customized login?

Comment: OK, I am happy that everything is working, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If WordPress gives you the message "ERROR: Invalid username." then WordPress has connected to the database. If it is not connected to the database it gives a message like "Error establishing a database connection". In particular **with respect to the database connection the username and password in wp-config.php is correct**, so I don't think you should delete it. **The problem really is exactly as stated you have entered the wrong username.** If you entered the wrong password the error message would be "ERROR: The password you entered for the username XXXXX is incorrect."

Since, you have access to the database you can get correct user logins from the wp_users table (adjust 'wp' prefix to whatever is used on your installation) from the column user_login. The user with ID==1 is usually an admin account.

You can get a list of ID's for admin users using the following MySQL command:

```
select user_id from wp_usermeta where meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' and meta_value like '%administrator%';
```

If after you have obtained a valid user and you cannot remember the password get the email address for that user from the column 'user_email' and using the link 'Lost your password?' at the bottom of the login form request and request a password reset.

Comment: *"The user with ID==1 is always an admin account"* -- That's not necessarily true.

Comment: You are right but I think it would be very unusual for this not to be true. Thanks for the heads up.